# Changing font size on a list using the CSS Style in Content Editor Webpart

Tags: css

I am trying to change the font size of the body of a SharePoint 2013 list (in datasheet view. I added the following CSS code in the content editor webpart, however the font only affected the first column (associated rows) of the list (not all of them). How to I get it to affect all the data in the list?

.ms-vb, .ms-vb2 {font-size: 8pt;}

Comment: try adding `!important` to your css, like: `.ms-vb, .ms-vb2 {font-size: 8pt !important;}`

Comment: FYI, real CSS developers will shun you for using ``!important`` and not using CSS Specificity, this has been around for over a decade... https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/